# How to preview in Blender Video Editor?

Tags: edit-mode, video

I'm a complete noob, and I've spent hours trying to find an answer to this question to no avail.
I've gone through a few tutorials and a few blender questions here on this forum but none of the advice was able to help me.
How do you preview your video so you can actually see what you're doing while editing? In After Effects it's called preview. In Blender I think it's called Proxy/timecode, I was never able to find that option though.

Always when I hit play at the bottom I just get to watch the first 8 seconds of my video looping. That's all I got to work. I would like the video to be watchable from any place I scroll and for longer than 8 seconds.
Please help
thx

[[image: I know the preview window. It's open when I first open the tool. But all I see through it are the places in the video that I scroll through and when I hit play I see the first 8 seconds of it in a loop.]

I know the preview window. It's open when I first open the tool. But all I see through it are the places in the video that I scroll through and when I hit play I see the first 8 seconds of it in a loop.

Comment: if you open a Video Editor window and switch it to Preview mode you should be able to see the whole sequence, maybe show a screenshot?

Comment: I added a screenshot. Hope it helps

Comment: This catches me out every time I open a video editor...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *End Frame* is set to 250 frames, increase this value (bottom right of your *Timeline* editor), otherwise it will only play 10 seconds. You can also display seconds rather than frames: enable *View > Show Seconds*.

[image]

Comment: oh wow amazing, I'm surprised how fast this preview works. 
In AE I'm used to having to wait for things to buffer before I can watch anything. But here it just all works in realtime. De hek is up with that?
I just set it to 1000000000 which works great but will prbly be a worse and worse idea the more complex my project gets. 
thx m8, u'r awesome ^^